# Proving ${\mathbb{P}}^n$ is Hausdorff

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, quotient-spaces, projective-space

I am trying to understand and complete the proof that the real projective space  ${\mathbb{P}}^n$ is Hausdorff.In my notes it is modeled as${\mathbb{R}}^{n+1}\setminus \{0\}/\sim  $ and it goes like this:

**It is enough to construct, given two different points $[a]$ and $[b]$
a continuous function $f:{\mathbb{P}}^n \rightarrow {\mathbb{R}} $ such that $f[a] \neq f[b] $ (why ?.......(1))**

**We fix $\omega$ in ${\mathbb{R}}^{n+1}\setminus \{0\}$  and define $f[\nu]$ as the squared of the distance from $\omega$ to the vector line $R\nu$ generated by $\nu$. Since  $f\circ \pi(\nu) = f[\nu] = |\omega|^2-(\omega . \nu)^2/|\nu|^2$, it follows that $f \circ \pi $ is continuous and hence $f$ is continuous...(why?........(2))**
($\pi$ is the canonical projection $\pi : {\mathbb{R}}^{n+1}\setminus \{0\} \rightarrow {\mathbb{P}}^{n} $)
**It is then enough to take $w \sim a$ to have $f[a] = 0 \neq f[b]$ ...(*)**

I have two questions:

***1)why is (1) true ?***

At first I thought I could justify (1) like this:
**Since ${\mathbb{R}}$ is Hausdorff, $\exists $ open sets $A,B$ such that for $f[a] \neq f[b] $, $f[a] \in A$ and $f[b] \in B$, with $A \cap B = \emptyset$. By hypothesis then $[a] \neq [b] $  and since $f$ is continuous, $f^{-1}(A) $ and $f^{-1}(B) $ are open sets of ${\mathbb{P}}^n$ containing $[a]$ and $[b]$  respectively such that $f^{-1}(A) \cap f^{-1}(B) = f^{-1}(A\cap B)=f^{-1}(\emptyset)=\emptyset $. Then  ${\mathbb{P}}^n$ is Hausdorff**

But I don't think my proof is correct since  for it to work we need $f$ to have the property stated at (1) but the function $f$ that they propose later has that property only when taking one of the points fixed, say $a$ as $a \sim w$ as done in (*), and not for any two points as needed for the definition of Hausdorff space. Besides if w is the center of a circle (in the 2-dimensional case for instance there are two lines that have the same distance to w, that is the tangent lines, so (1) does not hold for any two different $[a] $and $[b]$)

***2)why $f \circ \pi $  continuous implies $f$ is continuous?***  don't think  I can compose with a continuous $\pi^{-1}$, since that function is not well defined since $\pi$ is not injective

[image]

Comment: Your proof for (1) looks correct to me. (2) comes from the very definition of the quotient topology

Comment: This is just a comment: You can prove this by realizing it as a quotient of $S^2$ by a free,properly discontinous action of $\mathbb Z/2$. With less technology: you can explicitly find pairs of neighborhoods for each pair of antipodal points separating them i the sphere using the fact that $S^n$ is Hausdorff. I agree with the previous comment, looks good

Comment: @Andres Mejia Thanks,  I knew about using the sphere (that s actually left as an exercise), but my problem was understanding the book I am reading as it is. For (1)  I think I can have  $[a] \neq[b]$  such that f[a] = f[b] which is not what is needed for the proof to work. Like fo example for n=2, w is the center of a circle and the squared distances to the 2 tangent lines(determined by $[a] \neq[b]$) are the same so f[a] = f[b]

Comment: @Didier Could you elaborate on (2)? the quotient topology involves only the canonical projection, not this function f

Comment: @J.C.VegaO If $X$ is a topological space, $\sim$ an equivalence relation on $X$ and $\pi\colon X \to X/\sim$ the canonical projection, then the quotient topology on $X/\sim$ has the following property: a function $f\colon X /\sim \to Y$ is continuous if and only if $f \circ \pi \colon X \to Y$ is continuous. In fact, the quotient topology is defined precisely to have such a property.

Comment: You have to replace $\mathbb R^n \setminus \{0\}$ by $\mathbb R^{n+1} \setminus \{0\}$.

Comment: @PaulFrost oops  fixed that. thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your proof of $(1)$ is correct. In fact, you can generalize to this lemma:

> A space $X$ is Hausdorff if for any two $x, x' \in X$ such that $x \ne x'$ there exists a continuous map $f : X \to Y$ to a Hausdorff space $Y$ such that $f(x) \ne f(x')$.

Note that $Y$ and $f$ are allowed to depend on $x,x'$. Also the converse is true (simply take $Y = X$ and $f = id$ for all $x,x'$).

Concerning $(2)$: The construction of $f$ does not make sense in the present form. Writing $f([\nu])$ means that you want to define it for the elements of $\mathbb P^n$. For each $\omega \in \mathbb R^{n+1} \setminus \{0\}$ define

$$ f_\omega :\mathbb R^{n+1} \setminus \{0\} \to \mathbb R, f_\omega(\nu) = \lvert \omega \rvert^2 \left(1- \frac{(\omega \cdot \nu)^2}{\lvert \omega \rvert^2 \lvert \nu \rvert^2}\right) .$$
It is obvious that if $\nu \sim \nu'$, then $f_\omega(\nu) = f_\omega(\nu')$. Thus $f$ induces a unique function $F_\omega : \mathbb P^n \to \mathbb R$ such that $f_\omega = F_\omega \circ \pi$. By the universal property of the quotient topology $F_\omega$ is continuous. Note that $F_\omega([\omega]) = 0$.

Now consider any two distinct points $[\nu],[\omega]$ in $\mathbb P^n$. This means that $\nu$ does not lie on the line $\mathbb R \omega$, thus $(\omega \cdot \nu)^2 < \lvert \omega \rvert^2  \lvert \nu \rvert^2$ (Cauchy-Schwarz). Therefore $F_\omega ([\nu]) \ne 0 = F_\omega([\omega])$. The function $F_\omega$ depends on $[\omega]$, but this is allowed.

*Remark:*

We could also work with $f_\omega(\nu) =\frac{(\omega \cdot \nu)^2}{\lvert \omega \rvert^2 \lvert \nu \rvert^2}$. This is the square of the cosine of the angle between $\omega$ and $\nu$. Then $F_\omega ([\omega])  = 1$ and $F_\omega ([\nu]) <  1$.

Comment: Does the $f_\omega$you have defined represents the squared distance from w to the line ? Because I don't understand why you have changed$ |\omega|^2 $to $1$. The given expresion seemed to follow from Pythagoras' Theorem. And isn't $\omega$ supposed to be fixed?,  f is a function of $\nu$ only

Comment: @J.C.VegaO You are right, I forgot the factor $\lvert \omega \rvert^2$.  But as you see, this factor is irrelevant for the desired conclusion. And yes, $\omega$ is fixed, but it occurs as a *parameter* in $f_\omega$.